# Shopify linking product using SEO handle

Tags: shopify

I followed the directions for the second way to tag a product to a blog

This is the website I used https://happypoints.io/shopify-add-products-to-blog-post-c2-stt-66/
This is the code that was entered
{% assign my_description = article.content | split: '=== split content ==='  %}

```
     {% assign  my_description_size = my_description.size | minus: 2 %}
      {{ my_description | first}}
     <div class="show-product-list">           
       {% if article.tags.size > 0 %}             
           {% for tag in article.tags %}
           {% paginate collections.all.products by 100 %}
           {%- for product in collections.all.products -%}
               {% if product.handle == tag %}
                  <div class="product_item">
                   {% include 'product-card-list' %} 
                 </div> 
               {% endif %}
           {%- endfor -%}
           {% endpaginate %} 
           {% endfor %}          
       {% endif %}
     </div>
       {{ my_description | last}}
```

after following all the directions I received  an error message saying

Liquid error (sections/article-template.liquid line 42): Could not find asset snippets/product-card-list.liquid

I am not sure why the product wont link to the blog using the seo handle

Comment: since the code already has this line do I have to add it again on line 43?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a line:

```
 {% include 'product-card-list' %}
```

That means Shopify expects to find some asset named product-card-list.liquid. Since it cannot, you get that error. Add that snippet of code, and your error will disappear.

Comment: since the code already has this line do I have to add it again on line 43?

Comment: Look in snippets for the file product-card-list.liquid. That is the file you are missing

Comment: thank you! now it says that the nesting is too deep. There wasnt a snippet with the exact words as product card list liquid. if i create a new snippet with this code thats what comes up. there is a product card liquid code page but so if I have to add it here i am not sure what  line to add it on.